# React Native/Expo Media Library exception when saving large assets to Gallery (Android external storage)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I made an app where a user can take multiple videos and concatenate them together using FFmpeg concat. I added an export video feature where you can export your concatenated video to your Gallery on your Android device. Currently I am using `Expo Media Library` but I am having issues with large files. It doesn't have to be a very large file. Ex. a 4-5 min. mp4 video recorded in 720p makes the `MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync()` and `MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync()` functions to hang and eventually throw a generic exception `Unable to save file to external storage`. With smaller files I have no issues. Is there another way to copy a video file from the app folder to the Gallery/External Storage?.

Comment: `Is there another way to copy a video file from the app folder to the Gallery?` Why dont you directly generate your file in a folder that can be indexed by the media store so the file becomes visible in 'gallery' apps?

Comment: @blackapps do you have a stackoverflow link to that? That would be a great solution for me! I searched but can't find anything on it.

Comment: ??? What would be the problem? I cannot imagine a problem. If you can generate a file in a folder then you can create it in any folder i would say. Just change the destination path.

Comment: @blackapps Expo allows me 2 paths: cache folder and app folder. Do you mean inside these 2 paths? I already created a folder inside the app folder where I save my videos but they are not visible in Gallery.

Comment: I do not know or use react-native or Expo so i have no idea. I'm pretty amazed that you would not have acces to a folder, where you (or Expo?) would later copy your file to, to generate your file directly there. But apparently you wanna do the copy not using Expo.

Comment: @blackapps React Native FS gives me the same access: cache and app folder. I have no idea what you are talking about. Do you have a link or something? Maybe it can help me.

Comment: Your apps folder path is something like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>/files. And for the cache something like that or /data/data/<package>/cache. And indeed files in those directories are not visible 'in Gallery'. Now you wanted to copy your file so it would bvecome visible. Well then you can copy it to the MediaStore using MediaStore functions. Or copy the file to a pubilc directory on /storage/emulated/0. So I'm talking about the path where you want to copy your file to.

Comment: @blackapps `\storage\emulated\0\`` isn't writable anymore. It was depricated a while back. Currently I can only access it via de `MediaLibrary`. I think your `MediaStore` is something similar to the `MediaLibrary` but I am having issues with large files with this library.

Comment: You can still write your video file to /storage/emulated/0/Movies or maybe /storage/emulated/0/Video or /storage/emulated/0/Music.

Comment: @blackapps I can't. When I try to save it to /storage/emulated/0/Video or /storage/emulated/0/Music I get an exception that the folder doesn't exist. When I try to create it I get the exception that its not writable.

Comment: Which Android version on used device?

Comment: @blackapps android 11, I am using the latest react native and expo libraries. I have the external storage write and read permission including the legacy permission in the android manifest file.

Comment: The Android 11 devices that i tested all have a public Movies directory without i did anything. And my apps can create .mp4 files in it.

Comment: @blackapps with `/storage/emulated/0/Movies` is working but it still doesn't show up in the Gallery.

Comment: That is normal behaviour. Although on an Android 11 device often the MediaStore is updated right away too. Apparently it is not. Then you have to invoke the mediascanner on your file in order for the the file to be indexed in the MediaStore. After that you will see it in 'Gallery apps'. And as you know i do no react-native.. so dont ask me how to do that..

Comment: @blackapps I changed the path to `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` and now its working. It shows up automatically. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with the help of @blackapps, I am not sure if its a good solution but it is currently working for me.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
const path = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/video.mp4";
```

I am using the **React Native File System** library and I am directly generating my video file to the **DCIM** folder located at `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM`.

This only works through the **FFmpeg command**. If I try to copy the video to the DCIM folder with the File System library I will get an exception: `Its not writable`